# How to change data in a column using the longer length of a string in PANDAS?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, format, string-length

I have a dataframe with two columns: name and id.
In some cases the names are repeated, and can also be abbreviated, but they'll always have the same ID, example:

```
     NAMES          ID
 1. Peter Elliot  12345678

 2. Peter Elliot  12345678

 3. Peter E.      12345678

 4. Lucas Kershaw 87654321

 5. Lucas Kershaw 87654321

 6. Lucas Kershaw 87654321

 7. L. Kershaw    87654321
```

... other's names and id's...

So my objective is to format the names using the longer length of string, using as reference the ID.

The result should be:

```
     NAMES          ID
 1. Peter Elliot  12345678

 2. Peter Elliot  12345678

 3. Peter Elliot  12345678

 4. Lucas Kershaw 87654321

 5. Lucas Kershaw 87654321

 6. Lucas Kershaw 87654321

 7. Lucas Kershaw 87654321
```

... other's names and id's...

I've tried something like this:

```
a = np.asarray(general['ids']

for j in range(len(a)):

    ToF = df['ids'] == a[j]   
    filts = df[ToF] 
    filtdf = filts.loc[filt, ['names']] 
    read_longer_string = filt400.names.astype(str).map(len)

    if read_longer_string.argmax() == read_longer_string.argmin():
        print('nothing should happen')

    elif read_longer_string.argmax() != read_longer_string.argmin():
        longer_string = filtfd.loc[read_longer_string.argmax(), 'names']   
        df['names'] = df['names'].where(filt == False, df['names'].apply(longer_string.format), errors = 'ignore')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) with [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['NAMES'] = (df.loc[df['NAMES']
                 .str.len()
                 .groupby(df['ID'], sort=False)
                 .transform('idxmax'),'NAMES'].values)
print(df)
           NAMES        ID
1   Peter Elliot  12345678
2   Peter Elliot  12345678
3   Peter Elliot  12345678
4  Lucas Kershaw  87654321
5  Lucas Kershaw  87654321
6  Lucas Kershaw  87654321
7  Lucas Kershaw  87654321
```